# Brand new odoo installation

Tags: odoo

[image]I have installed brand new odoo 10 version and getting this error. I have 2 odoo installations with 2 environmentalist odoo9 is working ok, but when i switch to odoo10 getting this error just after i run database and try to connect to localhost.

```
    2017-04-20 19:20:21,036 5916 ERROR 10_blabla werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/grf/virtualenv/odoo/10.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 193, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/home/grf/virtualenv/odoo/10.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 181, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/grf/vcs/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 246, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/home/grf/vcs/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 184, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/grf/vcs/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 170, in application_unproxied
    result = handler(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/grf/vcs/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1306, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/grf/vcs/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1280, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/home/grf/virtualenv/odoo/10.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 599, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/grf/vcs/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1471, in dispatch
    result = ir_http._dispatch()
  File "/home/grf/vcs/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 199, in _dispatch
    return cls._handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/grf/vcs/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 169, in _handle_exception
    return request._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/grf/vcs/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 766, in _handle_exception
    return super(HttpRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/grf/vcs/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 195, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/home/grf/vcs/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 825, in dispatch
    r = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/grf/vcs/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/grf/vcs/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 119, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/grf/vcs/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/grf/vcs/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/grf/vcs/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/grf/vcs/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 440, in web_client
    context = request.env['ir.http'].webclient_rendering_context()
AttributeError: 'ir.http' object has no attribute 'webclient_rendering_context'
```

**UPDATE**
1 more error

```
2017-04-21 06:13:04,897 4479 ERROR newdb odoo.modules.registry: Failed to load registry
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/grf/vcs/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 78, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/home/grf/vcs/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 339, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module)
  File "/home/grf/vcs/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 237, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
  File "/home/grf/vcs/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 131, in load_module_graph
    model_names = registry.load(cr, package)
  File "/home/grf/vcs/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 261, in load
    model = cls._build_model(self, cr)
  File "/home/grf/vcs/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 540, in _build_model
    raise TypeError("Model %r inherits from non-existing model %r." % (name, parent))
TypeError: Model 'ir.qweb.widget.precision' inherits from non-existing model 'ir.qweb.widget'.
2017-04-21 06:13:04,900 4479 CRITICAL newdb odoo.service.server: Failed to initialize database `newdb`.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/grf/vcs/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 898, in preload_registries
    registry = Registry.new(dbname, update_module=update_module)
  File "/home/grf/vcs/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 78, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/home/grf/vcs/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 339, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module)
  File "/home/grf/vcs/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 237, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
  File "/home/grf/vcs/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 131, in load_module_graph
    model_names = registry.load(cr, package)
  File "/home/grf/vcs/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 261, in load
    model = cls._build_model(self, cr)
  File "/home/grf/vcs/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 540, in _build_model
    raise TypeError("Model %r inherits from non-existing model %r." % (name, parent))
TypeError: Model 'ir.qweb.widget.precision' inherits from non-existing model 'ir.qweb.widget'.
```

Comment: Which python version did you use ?  I notice issue related to python libs / version. Python3.8 seems not compatible, need patch fix

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browser cookies then check.

Comment: done that, same result. i used different browsers, updated python library's, node js....

Answer (score 0):

Just check your port of config file and also check weather it is taking correct database or not means for odoo10 you have created new database. Check database while running odoo10 and make sure it only takes database which you created for running odoo10.

You can enter `db_filter` field in your config file to make sure that server is running on new database. Before running new server make sure you **logout** from your last database where odoo9 is running.

If you still facing issue just let me know. I will try my best to solve your issue.

Comment: [options]
    addons_path = /home/grf/vcs/odoo/addons-
   other,/home/grf/vcs/odoo/addons-
    submodules,/home/grf/vcs/odoo/addons
    addons_path = /home/grf/vcs/odoo/addons-
    other,/home/grf/vcs/odoo/addons
    admin_passwd = admin
    log_level = debug

this is my openerp_serverrc.  ||||| i tried to delete all databases and to use db_filter same result , tried to make new databases and tried like -i web,base -d newdb...

Comment: You just enter specific port value which is unique in odoo10 config file by using `xmlrpc_port`

After that if not work then change your config file like this:

**[options]
   xmlrpc_port=1086
   addons_path=/home/grf/vcs/odoo/addons ,/home/grf/vcs/odoo/addons,/home/grf/vcs/odoo/addons- other,/home/grf/vcs/odoo/addons- submodules
   db_filter=your_db**

After that if you are facing same issue let me know about that.

Comment: same result. added everything in config. for first time it open database management page when i go to http://localhost:1086/ but after that i get error when modules start to load, and after i always get errors straightaway and in browser Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Find it, odoo can't find `ir.qweb.widget` model.
Check your odoo addons folder.
Check that it is odoo-10 or not.
Try to run with --load=web command line argument.